# How can I sort a list of objects by a certain component in VB?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET 3.5, and I'm trying to sort a list of objects that stores the children of a certain object.

I want to sort the 'lstDocumentChildren' list by its date, as seen in the code named 'LastDate'.

```
                For i As Integer = 0 To mobjDocuments.Children.ChildrenCount - 1
                    mobjDocumentsDetail = mobjDocuments.Children.GetChild(i)

                    lstDocumentChildren.Add(mobjDocumentsDetail)

                    If mobjDocumentsDetail.enmClassState = clsGlobals.enmClassState.enmNewRowState Or mobjDocumentsDetail.enmClassState = clsGlobals.enmClassState.enmFillState Then
                        objListItem = New System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
                        objListItem.Text = intDocCount & "_" & mobjDocumentsDetail.DocumentName
                        objListItem.SubItems.Add(mobjDocumentsDetail.LastUser)
                        objListItem.SubItems.Add(mobjDocumentsDetail.LastDate)
                        objListItem.Tag = mobjDocumentsDetail
                        'ManageMediaFiles.Items(0).c()
                        mobjlvMediaFiles.Items.Add(objListItem)
                        'ManageMediaFiles.rows()

                        'mobjlvMediaFiles.Columns(0).Text = "Media Files of Document : " & objEBDocument.DocumentName

                        'objEBDocument = CType(mobjlvDocuments.Items(0).Tag, ebAPIDocument)
                        'mobjlvDocuments.Columns(0).Text = "Document : " & objEBDocument.DocumentName

                        intDocCount += 1
                    End If
                Next

                ' THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO MAKE IT SORT THE LIST /////////////'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `lstDocumentChildren` is a `List(Of T)` where the specific type `T` has a `LastDate` property of type `Date`, the simplest option is to call the overload of the `Sort` method that takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate:

```vb
lstDocumentChildren.Sort(Function(x, y) x.LastDate.CompareTo(y.LastDate))
```

I'm fairly sure that that lambda expression will work in .NET 3.5. If it doesn't, you can use a named method instead:

```vb
Private Function CompareByLastDate(x As SomeType, y As SomeType) As Integer
    Return x.LastDate.CompareTo(y.LastDate)
End Function
```

and then create a delegate for that:

```vb
lstDocumentChildren.Sort(New Comparison(Of SomeType)(AddressOf CompareByLastDate))
```

I'm not sure but you may be able to simplify that to this:

```vb
lstDocumentChildren.Sort(AddressOf CompareByLastDate)
```

To learn more about sorting, you might benefit from reading my three-part [blog post](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html) on the subject.